# FirstResponder ignitable only in a little piece of a textView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

I have this textView in the inputAccesoryView, the case is that the textView have 80 of height and all the screen of width.

Problem: the finger will init the firstResponder only within the first 10 - 30 of height top to bottom. if you got the idea that means that the first 10 top pixels of the textView is not going to ignite the firstResponder, the space of ignition is 20 pixels and below of that.  Meaning that at this point the remaining 50 pixels doesn't work as well like the first 10 top.

Have anyone ever experienced this kind of behaviour? super weird.

Comment: Usually caused by the text view going outside its superview.

Comment: but that's not possible because the textView its anchored to the top and bottom of that super view that's how it is displayed.

Comment: I don't disbelieve you, but I don't believe you either. You are encountering an inexplicable phenomenon and you aren't providing enough information to allow it to be explained. I'm guess that somewhere there's a view that goes outside the bounds of its superview, because that is often a cause of an inability to touch a part of a view. If I'm wrong, prove it: provide more information.

Comment: messageInputTextView.setUpAnchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: sendButton.leftAnchor, topPadding: 4, leftPadding: 16, bottomPadding: 0, rightPadding: 16, width: 0, height: 80)

Comment: how do you suggest to debug this kind of behaviour? Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Use the View Debugger.

Comment: But unfortunately, I cannot see the firstResponder through the view debugger